# Improving inference time of my pytorch model after profiling

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to reduce the inference time of a model I have to put in production. I did not design it. It takes ~200/300ms to infer.

I did the following to profile it :

```
with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU], record_shapes=True) as prof:
      with record_function("model_inference"):
        trainer.test(model=model, datamodule=dm)
```

Here are the results

[image]

Going from there, what should be my next steps ?

It seems the data loading is taking most of the time ? Does it mean my Dataset subclass is slow ?

I can also see that the `to(device)` method take ~12% of the total cpu time. I will only be using CPUs, can I remove the `to(device)` calls everywhere as they are useless?

Comment: 1) data loading is often the bottleneck for models 2) it's weird that to(device) takes all that time, it should be a no-op if device='cpu'

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the `num_workers` based on number of CPU cores in your system and `prefetch_factor` to load the data in advance. These settings might improve your data loading speed.

Also, if you're not trianing on GPU then you can set `device="CPU"`.